# how to properly use git with network disk drives

Tags: git, network-drive

I was wondering if someone could give me some advice on how to use git with network drives that change.

I had to copy the directory containing all of my source files to a network drive and now when I use anything pertaining to git I get the error `fatal: Could not switch to 'W:/': No such file or directory`

Is there a way to change the location that git is pointing to?

Did I not setup my git repository correctly?

Comment: Edit the `.git/config` file in your repo. That, or use the command-line tools like `git remote`.

Answer (score 0):

you can view your git remotes by using

```
$ git remote -v
```

This will output something like this:

```
origin  git@host:user/repo.git (fetch)
origin  git@host:user/repo.git (push)
```

You can change this remote by deleting it, then recreating it with your proper remote

```
$ git remote rm origin
$ git remote add origin git@myhost:user/repo.git
```

Or more simply

```
$ git remote set-url origin git@myhost:user/repo.git
```

Comment: When I use git remote -v I still receive there fatal error

Comment: This is a pretty terrible way of doing it. Use `git remote set-url origin ...` instead.

Comment: I had to edit the .git/config file to change the directory to match the directory that Windows cmd was using. I was then able to use git remote set-url origin to work correctly.\

Comment: @MadPhysicist not necessarily terrible, just more verbose.

Comment: It is not just more verbose, it actually deletes the branch label temporarily instead of just editing a single configuration option for it. In terms of robustness, this is much worse.

Comment: to each their own; i'll edit the answer to include `set-url`